# Loading firebase image on my own webview android

Tags: android, html, firebase, android-webview

I have download url of an image uploaded in firebase storage. Now I want to show this image on my own webview using `<img src="download_url">`. But it does not load the image.
I used another app available on play store. It successfully did the job (I used same html code nothing change).
Now here is my html code
`<img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/physicsladder.appspot.com/o/kinematics%2Fa.jpg?alt=media&token=afcbd7ac-5ae2-4263-b642-7998dc11581b" width="100%" >`

Here is my app code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;
    WebView web;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        web=findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        web.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        web.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        web.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);

        editText=findViewById(R.id.editText);


    }
    public  void btnclick(View view){
        web.loadData(editText.getText().toString(),"text/html;charset=UTF-8",null);
    }
}
```

I enabled many settings from android studio still fails
[image: My app screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the WebView does not recognize your URL as a valid URL because of the '%' in it.

The Firebase Storage URL creates its directory path following this pattern:

> root_folder / sub_folder / sub_sub_folder

would be

> [https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/'yourfirebaseapp'/o/'sub_folder](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/%27yourfirebaseapp%27/o/%27sub_folder) % sub_sub_folder

I do not know why, but the Webview does not accepts links containing '%' as a valid URL.
If you put an image on the root folder, your URL would be:

> [https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/'yourfirebaseapp'/o/'yourimage.jpg](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/%27yourfirebaseapp%27/o/%27yourimage.jpg)

And this pattern the Webview recognizes as a valid URL.

Not really a solution, but is a workaround. Maybe my answer can inspire people to give you better directions.